# RemoteInterface.jar does not exist on domain1/lib/applibs folder running EntAppClient on remote glassfish server

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, netbeans-8, glassfish-4

I'm following this tutorial: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html

Instead of running glassfish server on localhost, I have install a glassfish server on an virtual Ubuntu machine. I have deployed the EJBRemoteInterface and the EntAppEJB with the EntAppEJB-ejb session beans included on the remote virtual Ubuntu using Netbeans.

I have implemented the EntAppClient project on the Windows client machine with Netbeans, as well. I have import the EJBRemoteInterface.jar to the Libraries of the project.

When I run the EntAppClient project get the error:

```
C:\Users\ramon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EntAppClient\nbproject\build-impl.xml:981: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

When I look on the server log:

```
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [EntAppClient] : Specified library jar C:%5CUsers%5Cramon%5CDocuments%5CNetBeansProjects%5CEntAppClient%5CEJBRemoteInterface.jar does not exist: /home/ricky/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/applibs/C:%5CUsers%5Cramon%5CDocuments%5CNetBeansProjects%5CEntAppClient%5CEJBRemoteInterface.jar



The SSL certificate has expired: [ [ Version: V3 Subject: CN=Entrust.net Secure Server Certifica... (details)   

javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl    06-jun-2019 17:30:09.792    {levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1559835009792}
124     SEVERE  The SSL certificate has expired: [ [ Version: V1 Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root, OU="GTE... (details) 



javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl    06-jun-2019 17:30:09.788    {levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1559835009788}
123     SEVERE  The SSL certificate has expired: [ [ Version: V3 Subject: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authorit... (details)



The SSL certificate has expired: [ [ Version: V3 Subject: CN=Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority, OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited, OU=www.entrust.net/CPS incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), O=Entrust.net, C=US Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5 Key: Sun RSA 


INFO    Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...(details)  org.glassfish.admingui  07-jun-2019 22:17:33.561    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938653561}
92  INFO    Redirecting to /(details)   org.glassfish.admingui  07-jun-2019 22:17:32.960    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938652960}
91  INFO    Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.(details)     javax.enterprise.admin.rest     07-jun-2019 22:17:32.723    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938652723}
90  INFO    Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.10.4 2014-08-08 15:09:00...(details)   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler  07-jun-2019 22:17:30.530    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938650530}
89  SEVERE  The SSL certificate has expired: [ [ Version: V3 Subject: CN=Entrust.net Secure Server Certifica... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl    07-jun-2019 22:17:25.439    {levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1559938645439}
88  SEVERE  The SSL certificate has expired: [ [ Version: V1 Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root, OU="GTE... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl    07-jun-2019 22:17:25.421    {levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1559938645421}
87  SEVERE  The SSL certificate has expired: [ [ Version: V3 Subject: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authorit... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl    07-jun-2019 22:17:25.414    {levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1559938645414}
86  SEVERE  Exception while deploying the app [EntAppClient] : Specified library jar C:%5CUsers%5Cramon%5CDocume... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.core    07-jun-2019 22:17:04.758    {levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1559938624758}
85  SEVERE  Exception during lifecycle processing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specified library jar C:%5... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.core    07-jun-2019 22:17:04.742    {levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1559938624742}
84  SEVERE  Exception while deploying the app [EntAppClient](details)   javax.enterprise.system.core    07-jun-2019 22:17:04.741    {levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1559938624741}
83  INFO    visiting unvisited references(details)  javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common     07-jun-2019 22:17:04.735    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938624735}
82  INFO    Java Web Start services stopped for the app client EntAppClient(details)    javax.enterprise.system.container.appclient     07-jun-2019 22:17:04.240    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938624240}
81  SEVERE  The SSL certificate has expired: [ [ Version: V3 Subject: CN=Entrust.net Secure Server Certifica... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl    07-jun-2019 22:16:10.480    {levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1559938570480}
80  SEVERE  The SSL certificate has expired: [ [ Version: V1 Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root, OU="GTE... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl    07-jun-2019 22:16:10.479    {levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1559938570479}
79  SEVERE  The SSL certificate has expired: [ [ Version: V3 Subject: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authorit... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl    07-jun-2019 22:16:10.469    {levelValue=1000, timeMillis=1559938570469}
78  WARNING     Context path from ServletContext: differs from path from bundle: /(details)     javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security  07-jun-2019 22:16:08.892    {levelValue=900, timeMillis=1559938568892}
77  INFO    Loading application __admingui done in 11.913 ms(details)   javax.enterprise.system.core    07-jun-2019 22:15:21.716    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938521716}
76  INFO    Loading application [__admingui] at [/](details)    javax.enterprise.web    07-jun-2019 22:15:21.711    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938521711}
75  INFO    Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) p... (details)   javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config   07-jun-2019 22:15:17.507    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938517507}
74  INFO    visiting unvisited references(details)  javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common     07-jun-2019 22:15:14.579    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938514579}
73  INFO    visiting unvisited references(details)  javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common     07-jun-2019 22:15:14.572    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938514572}
72  INFO    visiting unvisited references(details)  javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common     07-jun-2019 22:15:14.544    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938514544}
71  INFO    Virtual server server loaded default web module(details)    javax.enterprise.web    07-jun-2019 22:15:13.508    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938513508}
70  INFO    Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web(details)    javax.enterprise.web.core   07-jun-2019 22:15:13.505    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938513505}
69  INFO    Created virtual server __asadmin(details)   javax.enterprise.web    07-jun-2019 22:15:12.802    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938512802}
68  INFO    Created virtual server server(details)  javax.enterprise.web    07-jun-2019 22:15:12.797    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938512797}
67  INFO    Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848(details)     javax.enterprise.web    07-jun-2019 22:15:12.711    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938512711}
66  INFO    Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181(details)    javax.enterprise.web    07-jun-2019 22:15:12.702    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938512702}
65  INFO    Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080(details)    javax.enterprise.web    07-jun-2019 22:15:12.683    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938512683}
64  INFO    visiting unvisited references(details)  javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common     07-jun-2019 22:15:11.430    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938511430}
63  INFO    JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://ricky-VirtualBox:8686... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.jmx     07-jun-2019 22:15:11.353    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938511353}
62  INFO    Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@1bcf7c2 as OSGi ser... (details)   javax.enterprise.bootstrap  07-jun-2019 22:15:10.545    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938510545}
61  INFO    Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 16ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676](details)   javax.enterprise.system.core    07-jun-2019 22:15:09.896    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938509896}
60  INFO    SSLServerSocket /0.0.0.0:8686 and [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=8686]] created(details)    javax.enterprise.system.jmx     07-jun-2019 22:15:09.716    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938509716}
59  WARNING     All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s). Using SSL implementation specific defaults(details)     javax.enterprise.system.jmx     07-jun-2019 22:15:09.549    {levelValue=900, timeMillis=1559938509549}
58  INFO    SSLParams =org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.ssl.SSLParams@17a5f31(details)       07-jun-2019 22:15:09.548    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938509548}
57  INFO    SSLParams =org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.ssl.SSLParams@17a5f31(details)       07-jun-2019 22:15:09.508    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938509508}
56  WARNING     All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s). Using SSL implementation specific defaults(details)     javax.enterprise.system.jmx     07-jun-2019 22:15:09.509    {levelValue=900, timeMillis=1559938509509}
55  INFO    Creating a SecureRMIServerSocketFactory @ 0.0.0.0 with ssl config = GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfis... (details)   javax.enterprise.system.jmx     07-jun-2019 22:15:09.449    {levelValue=800, timeMillis=1559938509449}
54  INFO    GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 (13) startup time : Felix (8.000ms), startup services(29.... (details)
```

I have tried to add the jar file to applibs folder on virtual ubuntu.
I have implemented EntAppClient on local glassfish on ubuntu as well and everithing goes ok, but I still get the ssl certificate error.

Comment: [1] Do you know why you are getting the error _"The SSL certificate has expired"_ in Glassfish's log? [2] It looks like there may be more to that log message that you didn't show. Update your question if the log is still available and it contains additional relevant information.

Comment: I don't know why I am getting the "SSL" error. I have update my question adding all the log file report.